# Are list comprehensions fully evaluated before being used in the rest of the code?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, internals

Consider the following code.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    var = [element for element in f.readlines()][3]
```

This question concerns the internals of Python, rather than the result.

Does Python calculate all the elements of the indexes in the entire list of `[element for element in f.readlines()]`, or does Python just calculate all of the elements until the third index?

Comment: It calculates all of them.

Comment: If you want to be able to abort the computation once some specific item has been found, you should use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension.

Comment: Worth noting that `f.readlines()` returns a list, so the list comprehension is actually redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It calculates all of them. You can verify with something like this:

```
>>> [(i, print(i)) for i in range(3)][1]
0
1
2
(1, None)
```

This isn't really "internal", because [this is well-defined behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) and list comprehensions can have side-effects (even if [they shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects)).